# Fast modular exponentiation when Euler's Theorem doesn't apply

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I want to write an algorithm to reasonably efficiently calculate $a^L \pmod n$ where $a$ and $n$ are reasonably small (ten digits or so), and $L$ is unreasonably large (billions of digits).  I can efficiently calculate $L \pmod m$ for any reasonably small modulus $m$.

Euler's theorem tells us that, when naturals $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, for any $b$,

$$ a^b \equiv a^{b \text{ mod } \phi(n)} \pmod n$$

where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  This can also be expressed as $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

However, this doesn't apply when $a$ and $n$ have a common factor.  For instance, $10^x \equiv 1 \pmod{18}$ only holds when $x = 0$.

I conjecture that, for any naturals $a$ and $b$ and $n$, that $a^b \equiv a^{f(b)} \pmod n$ where

$$f(b) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
b & \mbox{if } b \le \phi(n) \\
\phi(n) + (b \mbox{ mod } \phi(n)) & \mbox{if } b > \phi(n)
\end{array}\right.$$

I've exhaustively tested this for $n \le 1000$.  If this is generally true, then I can confidently transform any of my big exponents to a reasonable ($\le 2\phi(n)$) size.  Can anyone prove this, point me at an established equivalent theorem, or provide a counterexample?

Comment: Wouldn't $((b-\phi(n)) \mod \phi(n))$ just be equal to $(b \mod \phi(n))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(n)+(b \pmod \phi(n))=t$

Also let  $ \frac{n}{gcd(n, a^t)}=s$

Also let $b=k\phi(n)+r$

If $b> \phi(n)$ then $b \geq t$

Then $a^{b} \equiv a^t \pmod n $ is equivalent to $a^{b-t} \equiv 1 \mod \frac{n}{gcd(n, a^t)}$

So, its enough to prove $a^{b-t} \equiv 1 \mod \frac{n}{gcd(n, a^t)}$

Now, since $gcd(a, \frac{n}{gcd(n, a^t)})=1$ by euler's theorem

we have

$a^{\phi(s)} \equiv 1 \pmod s$.

Clearly $s|n$. So, $\phi(s)| \phi(n)$.

So, let $\phi(n)=g\phi(s)$

Raising both sides to  $g$ in $a^{\phi(s)} \equiv 1 \pmod s$ we have

$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod s$.

Also $b-t=k\phi(n)+r-\phi(n) -(b \mod \phi(n))=(k-1)\phi(n)$

So, now raise both sides of $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod s$ to $k-1$

to get

$a^{b-t} \equiv 1 \pmod s$ which is what we wanted to show.
So,  the conjecture is true.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @ASKASK , this proves that the conjecture of the OP is true.

Comment: @ASKASK , is my proof wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind (1) or (2). How do you know $\phi(n) \mid (b-t)$?

Comment: @ASKASK wait i will add the explanation in my answer.

Comment: @ASKASK, i edited. Also $a|b$ implies $\phi(a)|\phi(b)$ because any prime factor in $a$ is also in $b$.

Comment: I think you may have proven it, but the reasoning is all inside out and backwards and I can't quite confidently follow it.

Comment: @NovaDenizen, sorry for the inconvinience. I have edited my answer. I hope it is understandable now.

Comment: @MosBlack You prove that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod s$ but you never show it's equivalent to proving $a^b \equiv a^t \pmod n$, you just assert that it's equivalent.

Comment: @NovaDenizen its a basic property of congruences that $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is equivlent to $\frac {a}{d} \equiv \frac {b}{d} mod  \frac {m}{gcd m, d}$ provided of course that a/d and b/d are integers. If u kno eulers theorem then u shuld be  aware of this too.